# Angularjs + making a json string of content and expressions come to life

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying very hard to put a string from the server into my angularjs app.

From the server:

```
{ 
  "content": "<div><h1 ng-bind='model.title.text'></h1></div>",
  "model": "title": { "text": "yeah, its working" }
}
```

Controller (-after $http call)

```
$scope.model = data.data.model;
$scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.data.content)
```

HTML with scope access: `<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>`

Result 
sourcecode `<h1 ng-bind="model.title.text">{{model.title.text}}</h1>` - looks ok
Visual `{{model.title.text}}` - missing parse or interpolation or something. The expression doesn't get evaluated

Guess I could need a pointer :)

Comment: `trustAsHtml` and `ng-bind-html` does not compile the html.  So, you cannot use Angular directives inside the html as you are attempting.  If you have a template on the server, it is best to use `ng-include`.

Comment: Thank your for your response! I'll have a go at it.